# Int64 % Int32 gives Int64 result

Tags: c#, .net, long-integer

```
long longVar = 100_000_000_000;
int intVar = int.MinValue;
long result = longVar % intVar;
```

In this example, why result should be long? It cannot be more than Int32.MaxValue, why it was decided to make remainder Int64 in this operation?

Comment: My guess is that `long % int` isn't actually defined and that what you are really seeing is `long % long` with the `int` being promoted to a `long`. That would then of course have to return a long.

Comment: Yes, the int is implicitly converted to a long to make this work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the [C# specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#remainder-operator) only the following remainder operators are predefined for integer types:

```
int operator %(int x, int y);
uint operator %(uint x, uint y);
long operator %(long x, long y);
ulong operator %(ulong x, ulong y);
```

Hence in your case the compiler chooses the `long(long, long)` version, and casts `intVar` to `long` automatically. Then the result is of type `long`.

Comment: Aha! I did suspect that was the case but wasn't sure where in the spec it was! :)

Comment: @Ondrej Tucny Thanks, it explains everything. I thought maybe I am missing a case when it will only fit into.

Answer (score 0):

Because if you try to use Int32 in this situation will be OverflowException(maybe). And have any moments in which will be cast into bigger object. For example:

```
int firstNumber = 10;
long secondNumber = 100;
var result = firstNumber + secondNumber;
```

(result - long)
If you don't believe me you can check.

This is due to the automatic cast to the parameter type of a specific method. In your case, this is '%'. In the case of the '+' sign, you can override the statement and specify your own implementation of this statement.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, it just gives an example of how `int + long = long` without really explaining how that relates to the `%` operator...